# Надсилати чи відправляти листа?

Tags: вибір-слова

Скажіть, будь ласка, яке ж словосполучення правильне: "**надсилати** листа" чи "**відправляти** листа"?

На [Офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/dilova_mova/oformlennja_lista_zakordonnim_partneram/9-1-0-279) натрапила на таке речення: "Намагайтеся надсилати листи в конвертах відповідного розміру."

У сучасному [Словнику української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=13469&page=439) подається така інформація:

> ВІДПРАВЛЯ́ТИ, я́ю, я́єш, недок., ВІДПРА́ВИТИ, влю, виш; мн. відпра́влять; док.
>   1. що.Посилати, відсилати що-небудь кудись, організовувати відсилання, перевезення чогось.

Тобто з’являється ще третій варіант "**посилати** листа".

То ж як правильно? Чи є відмінність у використанні цих дієслів? Якщо так, то у чому вона полягає?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Російсько-український словник сталих виразів](http://ros-ukr-idioms.wikidot.com) надає такі варіанти:

> **отправлять, отправить письмо** надсилати, надіслати (посилати, послати, відправляти, відправити) лист (листа).
>
> **отправлять, отправить телеграмму** надсилати, надіслати (посилати,
>   послати, відправляти, відправити) телеграму.

В [консультації з культури мови](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine59-34.pdf) маємо докладний розгляд цього питання з висновком:

> Один популярний посібник з сучасної ділової мови містить таку пораду:
>   мовляв, посилати можна лист, а відправляти — телеграму. Чи справді це
>   так? У Словнику української мови читаємо, що дієслова посилати та
>   відправляти є синонімами і навіть тлумачаться один за допомогою
>   другого. Отже, посилати — ‘відправляти що-небудь поштою, передавати
>   через посильного; надсилати’; відправляти — ‘посилати, відсилати щось
>   куди-небудь, організовувати відсилання, перевезення чогось’. Тут же
>   цитовано наших класиків: «Кривинюк наганяє, щоб дописувала, бо має йти
>   на вокзал відправляти листа» (Леся Українка); «— Відправте свою пошту
>   та й підночуйте в мене» (М. Коцюбинський). Цю подібність і
>   взаємозамінність дієслів підкреслено й у тлумаченні слова телеграма,
>   яку можна давати (дати, посилати, послати), тобто ‘відправляти якесь
>   повідомлення телеграфом’. Відомий розмовний фразеологізм бити
>   телеграму. Наведені слова синонімізуються і з лексемою надсилати —
>   ‘доставляти, посилати що- небудь поштою або через когось; посилати’.
>   Пам’ятаєте, у Ліни Костенко: «Пишіть листи і надсилайте вчасно, Коли
>   їх ждуть далекі адресати..». Надсилати, як показують матеріали
>   картотеки Інституту української мови, можна матеріал, гроші, посилку,
>   відповідь, вітання, співчуття, запрошення, лист, бандероль,
>   повідомлення. Ці ж іменники поєднуються зі словом посилати. Слова
>   гроші та лист можуть вживатися й у родовому відмінку — грошей, листа.
>   Поширений вислів посилати бандероллю. **Отже, листа й телеграму можна і
>   посилати, і надсилати, і відправляти**